# Font-Awesome not working in Mozilla if HTML file is inside a folder

Tags: html, firefox, font-awesome

I have searched Google and found many solutions for this issue, but none of the provided solutions resolved it.

My project structure is as follows:

[image: Project structure]

In **index.html**, the code is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"> 
  <script src="../lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
  <i class="fa fa-car"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-car" style="font-size:48px;"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-car" style="font-size:60px;color:red;"></i>
</body>
</html>
```

This code works perfectly in all browsers except Firefox. If I place the **index.html** outside HTML folder and make the link like...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
```

... it works fine. But it doesn't work when the HTML file is inside a folder.

Comment: "mozzila"? The browser is called *Firefox* and the company that makes it is called *Mozilla* (one z, two ls).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox has security restrictions on accessing files outside the directory the HTML document lives in when loading files from the local file system. Fonts are one of the resources impacted by this.

Install a web server and request your files over HTTP instead.

Comment: Thanks for such quick response. I placed the code in WAMP and it started working. Thanks for the help. I was really scratching my head all day long.